# Como executar assembly inline em um código com variáveis em C?

Tags: c, assembly

A partir de um exemplo de um livro, consegui executar o seguinte código assembly (AT&T) com o gas, que retorna uma mensagem com o nome do processador:

```
.section .data 
output:
    .asciz "The processor Vendor ID is '%s'\n"

.section .bss
    .lcomm tam, 12

.section .text
.global main
main:
    movl $0, %eax
    cpuid
    movl $tam, %edi
    movl %ebx, (%edi)
    movl %edx, 4(%edi)
    movl %ecx, 8(%edi)
    pushl $tam
    pushl $output
    call printf
    addl $8, %esp   

    pushl $0    
    call exit
```

**Pergunta:** Estou tentando colocar o código inline em C, mas estou com dificuldades. Como defino minhas variáveis em C para que elas funcionem corretamente?
O código "tentativa" abaixo não deu certo, mas demonstra um pouco a minha dúvida:

```
#include <stdio.h> 

int main(void)
{   
    const int tam = 12;
    char *output = "The processor Vendor ID is '%s'\n";

    __asm__ (

            "movl $0, %eax;"
            "cpuid;"
            "movl tam, %edi;"
            "movl %ebx, (%edi);"
            "movl %edx, 4(%edi);"
            "movl %ecx, 8(%edi);"
            "pushl $tam;"
            "pushl $output;"
            "call printf;"
            "addl $8, %esp;"
    );

    return 0;
}
```

Gostaria de saber como fazer esse código inline em C que retorne o nome do processador. Comandos simples (sem .data ou .bss) eu consigo compilar e executar, mas sempre que tenho variáveis do .bss ou mesmo constantes do .data não consigo compilar. Como faço para que o fonte acima compile e execute de forma similar ao assembly ? Desde já grato pela atenção.

Comment: Relacionado: [Como verificar quais tecnologias a CPU suporta em tempo de execução?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/9494/como-verificar-quais-tecnologias-a-cpu-suporta-em-tempo-de-execu%C3%A7%C3%A3o)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Notação Básica

O esquema básico de uso de `asm` ou `__asm__` ou `_asm` ou `__asm` em C\C++ é o seguinte ([usando o GCC como referência](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html)):

```
asm [volatile] ( "SEU CODIGO\n\t"
                 "EM\n\t"
                 "ASSEMBLY"
                    : OperadoresDeSaída
                  [ : OperadoresDeEntrada
                  [ : Clobbers ] ])
```

Essa notação muda dependendo do compilador.

---

### Exemplos

Acho mais fácil explicar utilizando alguns exemplo. [Veja no ideone.](https://ideone.com/C6wyPW)

Supondo que você tenha as seguintes variáveis:

```
// Criando variáveis para interagir com assembly:
int foo, bar, var;
```

Você pode interagir com elas usando `inline assembly` da seguinte forma:

```
//    Em C, seria:
//        foo = 1;
//        bar = 2;
//        var = 3;
asm volatile ("movl $1, %0;"  // código assembly
              "movl $2, %1;"
              "movl $3, %2;"
              : "=r" (foo), "=r" (bar), "=r" (var) // variáveis de saída
              );
```

Os `=r` indicam para o compilador que o resultado daquela instrução deve ser enviado por meio de um registrador para a variável `%N`, onde N é o índice. Você também pode utilizar `=g` deixando o compilador decidir que meio vai utilizar para enviar o valor. [Mais detalhes na documentação.](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.4.4/gcc/Simple-Constraints.html#Simple-Constraints)

---

```
//    Em C, seria:
//        bar = foo * 2;
asm volatile ("movl $2, %%eax;"      // eax = 2
              "imul %%ebx, %%eax;"   // eax * ebx
              "movl %%eax, %0;"      // faz bar igual ao resultado.
              : "=r" (bar)    // variáveis de saída
              : "b" (foo)     // variáveis de entrada (ebx = foo)
              );
```

Nesse caso, o compilador passa o valor de foo para o registrador EBX, para então utilizá-lo no código assembly informado.

---

```
//    Em C, seria:
//        var = bar;
asm volatile ("movl %0, %%eax;"
              "movl %%eax, %1;"
              : "=r" (var) // saída
              : "b" (bar)  // entrada
              : "%eax"     // clobbers
              );
```

Faz `var` igual a `bar` usando o registrador EAX (repare no uso dos índices em %0 e %1). O terceiro parâmetro (clobbers) serve para dizer ao compilador que o registrador EAX será utilizado. Dessa forma, antes de executar seu código assembly, o compilador salvará qualquer conteúdo presente em EAX que será utilizado após seu código, liberando o EAX para você.

---

**Para obter o fabricante da CPU**

Então, você pode utilizar o seguinte código para chamar obter o fabricante do CPU. Utilizando `cpuid`:

```
    asm volatile ("cpuid" : "=a" (eax), "=b" (ebx), "=c" (ecx), "=d" (edx)
                          : "a" (op));
```

Onde, `eax`, `ebx`, `ecx` e `edx` são os valores dos registradores e `op` é a função do cpuid que será chamada. Com isso, variáveis `eax` e etc receberão o retorno de cpuid, que você utilizará para imprimir o fabricante do processador.

No Windows, você também pode chamar o código acima usando a seguinte função:

```
int regs[4]; // recebe eax, ebx, ecx, edx
int op = 0;  // código da função
__cpuid(regs, op);
```

Para isso, você deve incluir `intrin.h`

---

Exemplo no [**ideone**](https://ideone.com/tuNB6U):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <cpuid.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    // a função opcode CPUID:
    int op;  

    // registradores:
    int eax; 
    int ebx; 
    int ecx; 
    int edx;

    // parâmetro zero para CPUID indica que você quer o fabricante.
    op = 0; 

    __asm__ ("cpuid" : "=a" (eax), "=b" (ebx), "=c" (ecx), "=d" (edx)
                     : "a" (op));

    // Receberá os valores de EBX, ECX e EDX para sistemas 32bits:
    char vendor[sizeof(int) * 3 + 1]; 
    strncpy(vendor, (const char*) &ebx, sizeof(int));
    strncpy(&vendor[8], (const char*) &ecx, sizeof(int));
    strncpy(&vendor[4], (const char*) &edx, sizeof(int));
    vendor[12] = '\0'; // terminador nulo

    printf("CPU: %s", vendor);

    return 0;
}
```

O retorno dependerá do CPU e mostrará apenas o fabricante, usando a seguinte notação:

```
"AMDisbetter!" ou "AuthenticAMD" -> "AMD";
"GenuineIntel" -> "Intel"
"VIA VIA VIA " -> "VIA"
"CentaurHauls" -> "Centaur"
"CyrixInstead" -> "Cyrix"
"TransmetaCPU" ou "GenuineTMx86" -> "Transmeta"
"Geode by NSC" -> "National Semiconductor"
"NexGenDriven" -> "NexGen"
"RiseRiseRise" -> "Rise"
"SiS SiS SiS " -> "SiS"
"UMC UMC UMC " -> "UMC"
"Vortex86 SoC" -> "Vortex"
"KVMKVMKVMKVM" -> "KVM"
"Microsoft Hv" -> "Microsoft Hyper-V"
"VMwareVMware" -> "VMware"
"XenVMMXenVMM" -> "Xen HVM"
```

Observação: esse código é para x86. Para saber qual o modelo do CPU é um trabalho maior.

Referência: [Playing with cpuid](http://newbiz.github.io/cpp/2010/12/20/Playing-with-cpuid.html)

Comment: Na verdade eu queria entender bem o seu primeiro paragrafo. Minha dúvida primordialmente não é mostrar o fabricante do processador, e sim a interação entre o código C e o assembly. Eu tentei entender a primeira parte, mas não entendi muito bem.

Comment: @RafaelBluhm Adicionei alguns exemplos explicando melhor.