# Como chamar função em assembly inline a partir de código em C e vice-versa

Tags: c, assembly

Eu estou usando a sintaxe MASM para fazer os códigos abaixo.
Eu tentei com essa função, por exemplo:

```
__asm(
    "soma:\n"
    "push ebp\n"
    "mov ebp, esp\n"
    "mov eax, DWORD PTR[ebp+8]\n"
    "mov edx, DWORD PTR[ebp+12]\n"
    "add eax, edx\n"
    "pop ebp\n"
    "ret"
);
```

e executei essa chamada

```
int main(){
    int result;
    result = soma(10,7);
    printf("%d",result);
}
```

No caso, a função em assembly não foi definida para o C e então a chamada falhou.
Da mesma forma eu tentei fazer ao contrário:

```
int soma(int x,int y){
    return (x+y);
}
```

Com a seguinte chamada

```
int main(){
int result; /*Colocado em  ebp-12 neste caso particular */
    __asm(
        "push 7\n"
        "push 10\n"
        "call soma\n"
        "add esp, 8\n"
        "mov DWORD PTR[ebp-12],eax" /* coloca 17 no result */
    );
    printf("%d",result);

}
```

Analisei o assembly gerado no site [godbolt](https://godbolt.org) e ambos os códigos geram o mesmo assembly mas nenhum dos dois funciona. Entretanto, se eu usar assembly para a função e assembly para a call funcionará assim como se eu usar C para a função e C para a call. Eu quero juntar os dois de alguma forma.

Tanto o código em C quanto o código em assembly funcionará normalmente, mas qualquer uma das duas misturas falhou
O problema em ambas as misturas foi undefined reference to `soma'

O código em assembly compilará usando o comando abaixo

```
gcc -m32 -masm=intel sum.c
```

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [Como executar assembly inline em um código com variáveis em C?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/49892/como-executar-assembly-inline-em-um-c%c3%b3digo-com-vari%c3%a1veis-em-c)

Comment: Update: metade do problema foi resolvido a partir da sua sugestão

Answer (score 0):

Metade do problema foi resolvido após sugestão.
[Como executar assembly inline em um código com variáveis em C?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/49892/como-executar-assembly-inline-em-um-c%C3%B3digo-com-vari%C3%A1veis-em-c)
Desta forma a seguir é possível chamar uma função em C a partir de assembly inline.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int soma(int x,int y){
    return (x+y);
}   




int main(){
int result; 
    __asm(
        "push 7\n"
        "push 10\n"
        "call ebx\n"
        "add esp, 8"
:"=a" (result)
:"b" (soma)

    );
    printf("%d",result);

}
```

Uma possível solução para a segunda parte (sem estar 100% assembly inline) é retirar as instruções `push ebp` ; `mov ebp,esp`;
`pop ebp` e `ret` e fazer todo o corpo da função em assembly, de um modo equivalente.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int soma(int x,int y){
    __asm(
    "mov eax, DWORD PTR[ebp+8]\n"
    "mov edx, DWORD PTR[ebp+12]\n"
    "add eax, edx\n" /*  eax contém o valor a ser retornado da função */
);
}   




int main(){
int result; 
result = soma(7,10);
    printf("%d",result);

}
```

Ainda resta o problema de fazer a função **totalmente em assembly inline** e continuar sendo possível fazer uma chamada de função em C